# Captured pixel data using AVCaptureSession, how can I feed it to WKWebView via evaluateJavascript?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Using a `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` I do something along the lines of:

```
m_videoOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
NSNumber * framePixelFormat = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA];
m_videoOutput.videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:framePixelFormat forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];

...

AVCaptureDevice *VideoDevice = [self CameraWithPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionFront];

...

AVCaptureDeviceInput *VideoInputDevice = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:VideoDevice error:&error];

...

[session addInput:VideoInputDevice];

...

etc
```

Then from the delegate method `captureOutput:captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer fromConnection:connection` I call the following method to capture the frames:

```
- (void)copyVideoFrame:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
{
    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = (CVPixelBufferRef) CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

    CVOptionFlags lockFlags = 0;
    CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, lockFlags );
    assert( kCVReturnSuccess == status );

    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow( pixelBuffer );
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight( pixelBuffer );
    NSUInteger numBytesToCopy = bytesPerRow * height;

    void * startByte = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress( pixelBuffer );

    m_cameraWriteBuffer = [ NSData dataWithBytes: startByte length: numBytesToCopy ];

    @synchronized(self)
    {
        m_middleManBuffer = m_cameraWriteBuffer;
        m_cameraWriteBuffer = NULL;

        m_frameWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth( pixelBuffer );
        m_frameHeight = height;
        [_mediaDelegate processData:self];

        CVOptionFlags unlockFlags = 0;
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, unlockFlags );
    }
}
```

I'm basing myself off of [this tutorial which feeds video from an iPhone/iPad app into Adobe AIR through ActionScript](http://easynativeextensions.com/camera-tutorial-part-4-connect-to-the-camera-in-objective-c/)

**I'm already successfully pulling the pixel data in a 32BGRA format** but now the million dollar question is **how to feed the pixel data from the native app into an HTML app loaded by a `WKWebView` ?**

I am almost certain I'm going to have to feed it in chunks, somehow, as a string using the `evaluateJavascript` method. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the bytes to a base64 encoding string and pass that string to JS and convert it back

---

https://github.com/Daij-Djan/DDEnhancedJSBridge

disclaimer: my code -- and old ;)

The code passes images to and from JS -- I use a UIWebView but in this case the approach is the same.